# BOOL property on UIViewController changes on its own

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue

On viewController A I have a BOOL property wantsAsk set on it (nonatomic, assign) that I access by self.wantsAsk. When I segue to another view controller (vcB) I set its wantsAsk
to the same as vcA. When it is time to return to A, vcB's prepareToSegue method is called
and I get a pointer to vcA from the seque (segue.destinationViewController); but it shows the values of vcA all wrong. In particular, wantsAsk which should be (and was) YES is now NO.

I've tried to set a watchPoint on wantsAsk but it is never triggered. I use this general  device all the time, and wonder why it could be failing here.

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: I suspect you're re-instantiating the view controller each time you present it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are segueing back to your view controller A you are most likely reinstantiating it. So the new A view controller is different from the your original A view controller.

Instead, just skip prepare for segue from B to A. If you are using a navigation controller, let it take care of returning to A. If B is modal, just call `dismissViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you only use the setter methods for your property (i.e. you do NOT use _wantsAsk =, or whatever your synthesize'd var is) You can figure out exactly where it gets set by using a symbolic breakpoint.  Go to the breakpoints window and click on a symbolic breakpoint or using the default Xcode shortcuts press  cmd+opt+\  From there, add "setWantsAsk:" (without quotes). Run the program and check out the places where it stops.

[image: Symbolic Debugging]

Comment: As H2CO3 had it, I am re-instantiating the view controller. Apparently that is what segue does. That is why the BOOL is NO - just the default value for a BOOL. If I want to read the value correctly I need to use a delegate. Thanks to both for the help.